# How to wrap dynamically created elements using jQuery wrap()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, radio-button

I'm trying to generate a radio input element in jQuery Mobile. Should be like this:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="radio-a" /></label>
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
radio = $("<input />")
 .attr({
   "name": "radio-" + this.uuid + "-" + i,
   "type": "radio"
 })
 .wrap("<label></label>")
 .appendTo(someElement);
```

My problem is the `.wrap()` does not work = the element gets created and appended correctly, but the `<label>` element is missing. Adding `id` and `for` attribute does not help.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: wrap returns the original object, not the wrapping container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `parent()` between `wrap` and `appendTo`:

```
radio = $("<input />")
 .attr({
   "name": "radio-" + this.uuid + "-" + i,
   "type": "radio"
 })
 .wrap("<label></label>")
 .parent()
 .appendTo(someElement);
```

Comment: that's what I did. Thanks!